# Unexpected IF in MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following procedure? MySQL says it is an 'unexpected IF'. I looked up the syntax for an IF statement and I simply don't see what the problem is.

```
create procedure spInsertAccount
(
AccountID INT,
InUse bit,
IsBanned bit,
IsPremium bit,
IsGolden bit,
Username VARCHAR(20),
Password VARCHAR(20),
Email VARCHAR(65),
LoggedInID INT,
CreateDate DATETIME
)

    SET @accountExists = (SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);

    IF (accountExists > 0) THEN

   INSERT IGNORE INTO Accounts(AccountID, InUse, IsBanned, IsPremium, IsGolden, Username, Password,
                        Email, LoggedInID, CreateDate
                       )
        values (@AccountID, @InUse, @IsBanned, @IsPremium, @IsGolden, @Username, @Password,
               @Email, @LoggedInID, @CreateDate);
        #where NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);

    END IF;
```

Comment: for starters, I think you're missing the BEGIN statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

Also check out here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

```
DELIMITER //  
create procedure `spInsertAccount`
(
IN AccountID INT,
IN InUse bit,
IN IsBanned bit,
IN IsPremium bit,
IN IsGolden bit,
IN Username VARCHAR(20),
IN Password VARCHAR(20),
IN Email VARCHAR(65),
IN LoggedInID INT,
IN CreateDate DATETIME
)
BEGIN
    SET @accountExists = (SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);

    if (accountExists > 0) THEN 
        INSERT IGNORE INTO Accounts(AccountID, InUse, IsBanned, IsPremium, IsGolden, Username, Password,Email, LoggedInID, CreateDate)
        values (@AccountID, @InUse, @IsBanned, @IsPremium, @IsGolden, @Username, @Password,
               @Email, @LoggedInID, @CreateDate);
        #where NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);

    END IF;
END //
```